# MySQL - Error Code: 1070. Too many key parts specified;

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following code in mysql but am getting the following error:

```
Error Code: 1070. Too many key parts specified; max 1 parts allowed 0.0011 sec
```

The original sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RecordLocation3 (
    id BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    typeId BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    symbolId INT NOT NULL,
    value POINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (symbolId, value, typeId, id),
    KEY k_id (id),
    SPATIAL KEY k_value (value)
) ENGINE= MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

Anyone have any idea how to increase the number of key parts?

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: I've never seen this error, to be honest, but my guess is that the spatial index/columns are the root cause.  I don't think that MyISAM (or InnoDB) has any problem with a composite key consisting of 4 columns.  You might need to switch DB engines.

Comment: What about this topic https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,390104,390104

Comment: Well @EugeneAnisiutkin it runs just fine with `COLLATE=latin1_bin` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7E586wYjtHZK1aYXnHijN/0 Edited not on MySQL 8.0 (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7E586wYjtHZK1aYXnHijN/1) it seams so i assume the topicstarter is using MySQL 8.0?

Comment: Run fine on rextester too  https://rextester.com/JRYV95522  Version 5.7.12

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin any idea why run ok in rextester?

Comment: Yes I'm using MySQL 8. I will try use an older version and see if it works out.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `value` is in the primary key alongside other columns of different datatypes. 
I just figured this out by trial and error. In MYSQL 8 you cannot have a key of mixed components if one ore more is a spatial type.
Take value out of the primary key and it should work.
An auto incrementing column would work better for a PK anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using MySQL 5.7.24 for Mac OSX.

Using version 8.0+ didn't work.

I guess the framework i was using didn't support a later version of mysql.